# How to show some few attributes on woocommerce category page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show two of many attributes of my products on category pages namely heating capacity and cooling capacity as i am making an online store in woocommerce and i am working with my custom theme. it is not a variation or something it's just a normal attribute with text which i would like to show something like [this](https://www.airconditioning-online.com.au/hitachi/split_system) as you can see the heating and cooling system listed on the category page itself i tried the code

```
if (!function_exists('shop_attributes_in_loop')) {
function shop_attributes_in_loop(){
    global $product;
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        if(!empty($attributes)){
            $attribute_single = array_keys($attributes);
            $myArray = array();
        echo '<div class="product_attributes">';
            foreach ($attribute_single as $attribute => $value) {
                $myArray[] = ucfirst($value);
            }
        echo implode(', ', $myArray).'</div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_attributes_in_loop');
```

but it shows something wierd like 
**Placement-of-outdoor-unit, Installation, Pa_model-no-indoor, Pa_model-no-outdoor** etc.. can anyone help me..
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out how its to be done :)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_display_post_meta', 9 );

function custom_display_post_meta() {
   global $product;
   $attr = array('pa_cooling-capacity-watts', 'pa_heating-capacity-watts');
   foreach ( $attr as $attribute ) {
   $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, Its working, but though there is only two attribute value needs, so better is avoid foreach. Because Category page have more loop. if you use another foreach loop you might get slow output. Actually here  "O" notation value n square happened.  Because here your foreach loop working as inner loop. Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet for getting custom field value at archive / category page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_display_post_meta', 9 );

function custom_display_post_meta() {
   global $product;

   $heating_capacity = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'heating_capacity', true );
   $cooling_capacity = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'cooling_capacity', true );

   echo $heating_capacity;
   echo $cooling_capacity;
}
```

you can read this article as reference: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-information-to-woocommerce-shop-page/

Comment: it helps me to find out how it to be done here is how i did it add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_display_post_meta', 9 );

function custom_display_post_meta() {
   global $product;
   $attr = array('pa_cooling-capacity-watts', 'pa_heating-capacity-watts');
   foreach ( $attr as $attribute ) {
   $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
 echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
}
}